# gvfs mount onto Ubuntu desktop of Nexus 4 running Touch doesn't show dot files

Tags: usb, nautilus, ubuntu-touch

I have 15.04 on a Nexus 4. I have a desktop running 16.04.1. When the phone is plugged into the desktop via USB, it shows up in the Launcher in the left and opens a Nautilus window. That window doesn't show hidden (dot) files. When I login to the phone, I can see the hidden files. I want to point out that the phone doesn't mount like a USB disk; I don't see it in the output of `df`.

When I select the "open" operation from the Launcher, it opens another window to the same view that has a path of 
`/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C010%5D/Nexus 4`.
That view also does not show the dot files. Now that I know the path in the filesystem, I can `cd` there and still do not see the dot files.

I want to look at sqlite files in the phone using a viewer installed on the desktop. How can I get to those dot files (without copying them to the desktop)?

Comment: Does it show when you enable viewing of hidden files/folders? -> CTRL+H in Nautilus...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have show hidden files enabled and no, it doesn't show them. Nor does "ls -a" in a terminal.

Comment: It's possible to install `sshd` on the phone for remote access but that's not really a proper solution IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not see them because you are useing an mtp protocol when you connect the phone..
That's how it is..
You can modify those file from the terminal with nano.
Hope this help.